# Why are parts of my mesh disappearing during animation?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, unity

I'm a novice at Blender so I'd appreciate any feedback. I created an animation for a publicly available model I found online: https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/fantasy-character/low-poly-adventurer

But when I imported the fbx into Unity and ran the animation, parts of the mesh were see through. The see through parts were the Main Mesh, of which only a few faces appeared to be floating in space. Interestingly when not in animation mode the model was properly textured.

[image]

What the model looks like when animation is played

[image: What the model should look like]

What the model should look like (not animated)

I'm not sure what's going on since it's my first time animating. I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the model rather than something in Unity, since I pretty much imported the model without any changes. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using Blender version 3.6.4

Comment: Hello, if the character is copyright free, could you please share the file (the site you point to asks to subscribe)?